# How USB OTG virtual COM port device operation can work with Windows 10 IOT OS?

Tags: drivers, windows

I am trying with minnowmax (https://www.elinux.org/Minnowboard:MinnowMax) with USB OTG option on windows 10 IoT platform for Device operation. What will be the way to write a driver to configure the device as a virtual com port device and start to communicate from Putty(Host device). Can you please elaborate more on this?

Comment: Welcome to the site. It looks very much like your question is (1) one on programming that might better be asked on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com), and (2) one about programming drivers for Windows. It would seem off-topic for a Linux&Unix forum ...

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this isn't about Unix or Linux.